# I can't find my Android App in Google Play with the searcher but it is in the platform if you know the url

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

The name of my App is Gestión Escáner. I search "Gestión Escáner" (without quotes) and I see a lot of apps less mine. I have another app in published and if I go into it in the store I can access to the creator (Me) and then see my 2 apps (Gestión Horario and Gestión Escáner) witch I couldn't find in the searcher.

Is ridiculous that I search my app by it name and I found nothing. I published the app 2 days ago and in the web page Google says that the publishing take as maximum 24 hours.

My app is published, it can be checked in the Google Play Console, and in the Google Play Store (if you know how to exactly search it).

There is a Google failure or something? I can't reach understand why I cannot find my App by its name.

I want to specify that there no exists another application with the same name as mine.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Actually at the time of uploading the content of the app , you have to define tags (best suitable word according to you app ) . you may miss that . 
so write in your description like   
`Keywords: keyword1, keyword2, keyword3`

Comment: It takes time for the google crawlers to actually analyze an app and make it legit for the search. It checks all the links such as privacy policy and the website link. You will see a better search progress after a week.

Comment: @TalhaBilal can I access to that descriptions in the google play console without to release a new other build?

Comment: @MtgKhaJeskai if this is your app and uploaded to your own google play console then you can access easily . just go to that app and change the description

Comment: Thank you. Let see if it works but seems that I will have to wait anyway

Comment: just to know you that, mine was visible after 2 days.. give it some time.

Comment: Thanks you @Sam. that info is apreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The time of 4 to 24 hours is the time to get app published.
After the app has been published, it needs to be indexed by google to be visible in the search. Also, the search results also depend upon the ASO(App Store Optimization). Sometimes, you can't see your app even with the full name without that. Make sure your Title/Description convey the idea.

You can read the following links [App visibility & discovery issues](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9042516?visit_id=636893686398829297-3238925166&hl=en&rd=1) and [Get discovered on Google Play search](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/4448378)

Comment: I have been reading those 2 links with no really useful info due to I have done all they say there. Anyway, what you say have sense. It's seems I will have to wait but I was scared about would be my mistake.